# Add UITextField to ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to add a UITextField to Scroll View programmatically. I have used bellow mentioned code segment

```
var sampleTextField = UITextField()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.contentSize.height = 1200

    sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(8, 88, 300, 30))
    sampleTextField.placeholder = "First Name"
    sampleTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    sampleTextField.tag = 400

    self.scrollView.addSubview(sampleTextField)

}
```

When i run the code, i could not see a text field on the scroll view.

but when i replace `self.scrollView.addSubview(sampleTextField)` with `self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)` i could see the text field in super view and it did not fixed with scroll view.

Please help me to add text field to the scroll view.
bellow attached image will help to understand the scene

[image: Scene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works form me.

Here is the set up in IB: Note there are no  UITextFields added here.

[image]

The code in the ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

   var sampleTextField = UITextField()
    var sampleTextField2 = UITextField()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.contentSize.height = 1200

        sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(8, 88, 300, 30))
        sampleTextField.placeholder = "First Name"
        sampleTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        sampleTextField.tag = 400

        self.scrollView.addSubview(sampleTextField)

        //

        sampleTextField2 = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(8, 144, 300, 30))
        sampleTextField2.placeholder = "Last Name"
        sampleTextField2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        sampleTextField2.tag = 401

        self.scrollView.addSubview(sampleTextField2)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

And when Run: Shows The UITextFields have been added

View using the Debug View Hierarchy :

[image]

And the App in the Simulator:

[image]